# Find function file which is calling it and outputting in the error log as NOT FOUND

Tags: php, wordpress

I am newly using Google compute engine (GCP). I have a limited knowledge on programming yet i am hosting WordPress website in my server.

The problem is few days back my site got hacked or access by someone else. I received a message from GCE customer support that my account will be suspended if I don't stop using server for mining cryptocurrency. Now I have no idea what he was talking. Then I checked the files and can see lots of foreign files. He is apparently using my server to mine crypto, though nothing malicious or disruption of server..

As I have lots of edited and custom files and that I don't have backup files, my best option was to manually check and remove all those foreign files.. I have almost removed all the files but still there are files continously calling from somewhere else function or something that is tracing NOT FOUND error in error.log and access.log.. Looks like using cron jobs or something.. I have no idea where it's coming from.. I am just trying to find that file that is executing those functions.

**error.log file:**

```
[Tue Nov 13 15:03:34.595848 2018] [:error] [pid 31561] [client 66.249.66.150:47822] script '/var/www/example.com/tozeowi.php' not found or unable to $
[Tue Nov 13 15:05:56.744506 2018] [core:error] [pid 31587] [client 176.9.23.3:36328] AH00124: Request exceeded the limit of 10 internal redirects due to probable configurat$
```

**Access.log file:**

```
"GET /joapow1ok/tozeowi.php?serhtr=morgan-stanley-health-insurance-benefits'A=0 HTTP/1.1" 404 3621 "https://www.example.com/joapow1ok/tozeowi.php?"
```

If someone can help me find that file causing to execute that GET function.. Or is there any linux function to find figure out. 
**Note:** I have disabled many plugins and my theme yet no luck.. I have 3 website in the same directory and all got infected.

Comment: I strongly think that even if you have removed the malicious files, you website will most likely get attacked again, if don't implement the security measures. Irrespective of hosting platform/environment wordpress is vulnerable to hacking if not configured correctly with security measures.

Comment: @zipkundan I have almost checked 90% of the files and it looks okay.. I believe those function files are in the core WordPress files which has thousands of files to go though individually..  For now I literally disabled upload or execute features other than myself.